# Can I use client-go to get kubelet info such like do "ps -ef | grep kubelet"?

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

Can I use client-go to get kubelet info such like do `ps -ef | grep kubelet`? Thank you~

Comment: `kubectl get --raw=/api/v1/nodes/$NODE_NAME/proxy/configz | jq .` can provide you the configuration information.

Comment: I mean such as use `ps -ef | grep kubelet` to get kubectl info use client-go